# No viable alternative at character " "

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, class

Second day of being a coder and I'm getting this error...

> line 1:70 no viable alternative at character '"' Error is in
> expression '{!search}' in component apex:commandButton in page
> unopenedcasespage: Class.UnopenedCases.search: line 6, column 1
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has
> been notified.

Here's the code...

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class UnopenedCases {
        public list <Case> cas {get;set;}
        public String searchKey {get;set;}
        public void search(){
            string searchquery='SELECT parentId.caseNumber, parentId.subject FROM case WHERE status = "0"';
            cas= Database.query(searchquery);
        }
        public void clear(){
            cas.clear();
        }
    }
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="UnopenedCases">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="Clear records" action="{!clear}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!search}"/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Search Result">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cas}" var="c">
                <apex:column value="{!c.subject}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.caseNumber}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I've tried unticking smart quotation marks on my mac and rewriting the whole thing but nothing I've tried has done anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Double quotes `"` are not used for `SOQL` query to specify a filtered value in conditional expression. You can use single quotes with escaping `\'`. Take a look at [Quoted String Escape Sequences](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm)

```
public void search(){
    String searchquery='SELECT parentId.caseNumber, parentId.subject FROM case WHERE status = \'0\'';
    cas= Database.query(searchquery);
}
```

Another option, to use variable binding

```
public void search(){
    String caseStatus = '0';
    String searchquery = 'SELECT parentId.caseNumber, parentId.subject FROM case WHERE status = :caseStatus';
    cas= Database.query(searchquery);
}
```

---

Moreover, I recommend you use static SOQL queries until you need to have them dynamic explicitly. Compile errors are earlier detected, than runtime exceptions.

```
public void search(){
    cas= [SELECT parentId.caseNumber, parentId.subject FROM case WHERE status = '0'];
}
```